pyodbc connect to sql server with TrustServerCertificate
I'm trying to connect to a SQL server instance using python and pyodbc.
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.0.1;Database=Db;User Id=Too;Password=Easy")

When I run this, I get the below error:

('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.\r\n (-2146893019) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722 (-2146893019)')

So we have a self signed certificate, this should be easy to fix, as we just add TrustServerCertificate
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.0.1;Database=Db;User Id=Too;Password=Easy;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes")

Which now results in a new error:

('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")

Removing TrustServerCertificate, but leaving Encrypt results in the below error:

('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.\r\n (-2146893019) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722 (-2146893019)')

Which suggests the problem, is something related to recognising TrustServerCertificate in the connection string.
So I try to set the value through attrs_before instead
SQL_COPT_SS_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE = 1228  
SQL_COPT_SS_ENCRYPT = 1223
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.0.1;Database=Db;User Id=Too;Password=Easy;", attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ENCRYPT : 1, SQL_COPT_SS_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE : 1})

Which again results in the error

Invalid connection string attribute (0)

What am I missing in order to connect to a SQL Server that's using a self signed certificate?

Sounds like you are passing the wrong login name and/or password. If you check the SQL Server's logs you'll be able to locate the real authentication error (authentication errors passed to the application are intentionally vague). If you don't understand that error, [edit] your question to include said error.

@ThomA Server, Username, password are all correct. As all the errors revolve around server certificates and/or the TrustServerCertificate parameter, it seems consistent to me

" Server, Username, password are all correct." Then you could not have got the error "Login failed for user ''." Either you didn't get that error, or the credentials you are passing are incorrect. The errors you are getting are all expected. If you use an encrypted connection (which ODBC 18 defaults to) and you don't have a trusted certificate you get error 1 (authentication won't even be attempted). If you force trust of that certificate, and pass wrong credentials you get error 2. If you force encryption you are effectively back at 1 again.

@ThomA This looks even more strange, I created a DSN instead, which connects to the server correctly when testing the connection. Trying to use the saved DSN via pyodbc and python gives a Login failed for user error, despite the connection being successful at creation.

Again, please "check the SQL Server's logs [where] you'll be able to locate the real authentication error. If you don't understand that error, [edit] your question to include said error."

Use UID= instead of User Id= and PWD= instead of Password=

@GordThompson That is exactly what is was! Do you want to write that as the answer for your internet points?

No, go ahead and answer you own question and I'll give it an upvote. :)

(as per Gord Thompson's comment) The connection string needs to use UID for user id and PWD for password
e.g.
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=192.168.0.1;Database=Db;UID=Too;PWD=Easy")

